# SSRS: Relative URL Hyperlink

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS 2008 I would like to create a relative path URL.  Long story short I have a subscription that outputs a few thousand static HTML pages to a folder that is used as content for a website.  In the past I have created full URLs to other pages on the site (sub-reports, really) using Text Box Properties -> Action -> Go to URL.  I would like to modify my code so that it returns the relative path of the target instead of the full URL.  This will reduce the likelyhood that someone will eventually break the navigation by changing the website domain or folder structures.  When I tried to make this work, the objects that were previously clickable are no longer, well, clickable.  **How do I make a SSRS hyperlink jump to a relative URL instead of a fully-qualified URL?**

Here's what works:

```
="https://some.domain.com/some_page/" + Fields!Custom_Page_Name.Value.ToString() + ".html"
```

Here's what doesn't work:

```
="../" + Fields!Custom_Page_Name.Value.ToString() + ".html"
="/" + Fields!Custom_Page_Name.Value.ToString() + ".html"
=Fields!Custom_Page_Name.Value.ToString() + ".html"
="..\" + Fields!Custom_Page_Name.Value.ToString() + ".html"
="\" + Fields!Custom_Page_Name.Value.ToString() + ".html"
```

Comment: relative to the current page?

Comment: Relative to the current rendered report file that's sitting on a file share somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the warning generated when you run the report in Visual Studio you'll get your answer:

> [rsInvalidURLProtocol] The value ‘test.html’ of the Hyperlink property of the text box ‘textbox6’ has an invalid schema.  URLs in reports may only use http://, https://, ftp://, mailto: or news:

i.e. URLs must have one of those protocols, and since there's no way of writing a relative URL when it starts with the protocol that means SSRS doesn't support relative URLs.

An alternative would be to set the base URL in a parameter, which would then be easily changed and would only require regenerating your html pages if it changes.

Comment: Not what I was hoping to hear, but I am glad to hear it.  I never noticed the warnings and this definatively answers my question.

Answer (score 8):

Just read this Q and A and have a better solution for anyone looking. If you want relative url then just use javascript e.g.

```
="javascript:void(window.navigate( '/mydirectory/reportcountry.aspx?CountryID=" + Fields!CountryID.Value.ToString() + "'))"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
="javascript:void(window.open(document.URL.replace('CurrentReportName','NavigateToReportName'),'Window1','menubar=no,width=430,height=350,toolbar=no'));"
```

I know it's a old post. it may help someone..Note: I am using SSRS 2008

Answer (score 1):

Just use global variable `Globals!ReportServerUrl`

So `"http://myservername/rs?/myreportname"` becomes  `Globals!ReportServerUrl + "?/myreportname"`

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server Data Tools you can access the property pages for a label.  This gives the option to link to another report (in the same project) and pass any parameters as required:

[image: Screenshot of property pages.]